# Utilize timer to update MFC Document/View application

Tags: c++, timer, mfc

I'm experimenting with a basic (template) MFC application, and I am looking to update the `CDocument` (representing the model) instance according to a timer event, for example, move a circle from one point in the client area to another point, according to elapsed time and velocity of the circle.

I've added the code to start the timer in the application class:

```
m_timer = m_pMainWnd->SetTimer( 16, 1000, NULL);
```

Which should send a timer message 60 times per second.
However, I'm encountering several issues:

Adding a `ON_WM_TIMER()` entry to the message map for the derived `CDocument` .cpp file does not work, citing a c2446 error (casting a member function pointer to void pointer).

Trying the same with the concrete `CView` class does not cause an error, but the `OnTimer` function is never invoked.

The only place where `OnTimer` is ever invoked is in the derived `CFrameWndEx` class, using the following signature:

```
afx_msg void OnTimer( UINT_PTR nIDEvent );
```

As far as I can tell, there is no way for the `CFrameWndEx` to invoke changes in either the `CView` or `CDocument` derived classes.

I'm pretty sure this is simply down to my seriously lacking knowledge of MFC architecture, so I would appreciate some pointers.

Comment: You can pass your own callback to [CWnd::SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49313fdf(v=vs.120).aspx) if you don't want the window class to handle timer messages.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes I'm aware of that, but it doesn't address the core issue, which is that I don't know how to use that to update the document/view based on the timer message. As far as I can tell, the `CFrameWndEx` object has no knowledge of either.

Comment: Can you post the signature of your `CMyDocument::OnTimer()` function?

Comment: People seeing your question are not getting the full picture. You need to say where you are putting the `ON_WM_TIMER()`, and the `OnTimer()` function. `ON_WM_TIMER()` on a `CDocument` will never be handled, because it is defined to be treated by `OnTimer`, which is in  `CWnd`. In the message loop there is some point on a `CWnd` that is calling `OnTimer`, a fact not happening on `CDocument` derived classes. I suggest you to use Spy++ (Spy++ 64 on 64 bits build) to see the message workflow running.

Comment: There is no MVC on MFC. What you have is **Document/View Architecture**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x1xy43a.aspx

Comment: @sergiol Yes, you are right, in a literal sense. However, from what I've been reading from other questions/answers here, the document can be seen as the model and the view seen as the controller/view.

Comment: For CView, likely OnTimer is not being invoked because you are calling SetTimer before the window handle of the CWnd has been created.  Create your timer in the CWnd::OnCreate message for example.

Comment: Apparently, you **can** install the timer at a place in your code, where you do have access to the document. So just store away the instance pointer to the document and use it in the callback (which must be a free function or `static` class member).

Answer (score 3):

Add an OnTimer function and and ON_WM_TIMER message macro to your CView derived class.  From the CView, you can call GetDocument().  That's the easiest way.  Documents are not windows so they cannot handle window messages.  The only thing they can handle is WM_COMMAND messages because of the way MFC gives the document a chance to respond to those messages via its command message routing.

Another way is to create a TIMERPROC function.

I recommend the first way.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I did the first way, and the OnTimer function was never invoked.

Comment: @IanYoung: You're going to have to show the relevant source code then. `CView` is derived from `CWnd`, so you can install a timer and have an instance of a `CView` (or `CView`-derived) class handle the timer messages.

Comment: m_pMainWnd->GetActiveView()->SetTimer(...)

Answer (score 1):

Like Joe Willcoxson suggested, simply put the `OnTimer` method within your concrete `CView`. However you then can't use the `SetTimer` method like you posted:

```
m_timer = m_pMainWnd->SetTimer( 16, 1000, NULL);
```

You have to call it somehere in your `CView` class, without `m_pMainWnd`, e.g. like:

```
CMyView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    m_timer = SetTimer( 16, 1000, NULL); // also nullptr instead of NULL would be nice
}
```

Otherwise the main window will always be the `CWnd` that handles the message.